# Print out all the output in R Console

Tags: r, printing, console

Say I have a large list called dummy

```
dummy <- rep(list(runif(1000)),1000)
```

and want to print it all in the R console

I set the max.print option to 10000000

```
options(max.print=10000000)
```

and the print is showing from element [[995]] to [[1000]] only!

I can export the output to a txt file

```
cat(capture.output(print(dummy), file="test2.txt"))
```

but for some demonstrations, is there a way to show all the list elements in R Console. From [[1]] to [[1000]]

Thanks

Comment: Why the heck would you ever need that?

Comment: Test the output and show students live

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, then you can create a r markdown and run the following :

````
```{r}
dummy <- rep(list(runif(1000)),1000)
dummy
```
````

However, the wait till all the result to load will be very long.